# Add textbox gmail - Browser Extension

Tags: javascript, ajax, gmail, greasemonkey, gmail-contextual-gadgets

Is there a JS framework or library to add text/check box to gmail UI?

Please note that the data contained there will be sent through AJAX - JSON object to a particular server.

Idea is to make a Chrome extension with this functionality.

Something similar to:

[image: GMAIL UI]

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write [Greasemonkey](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greasemonkey) script for that. It's supported by Google Chrome by default.

Comment: Is this better than Gmail  Contextual?https://developers.google.com/google-apps/gmail/contextual_gadgets#prerequisites

Comment: With Greasemonkey you can access to any element on web page. But with Gmail Contextual you will get some additional API. It's your choice what to use. Greasemonkey is more general. And with it you can write user-script for any web page in the web

Comment: What would be the additional API functions?